# google auth's data to be stored in database using next auth

Tags: next.js, google-oauth, next.js13, next-auth

I have implemented next auth on my website and have integrated google o-auth. the google login is working great however after a user successfully logs in i need to send a request to my backend in `flask with the name, email and access token`. I have added the code to send that data inside the async signIn function but its triggering the api call to my backend in spite of successful google login and even seeing the user data in the console

how do i trigger the api call to my backend after the user has logged in successfully with the payload

code, [...nextauth].js ->

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

export default NextAuth({
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET
        })
    ],

    callbacks: {
        async jwt({ token, account }) {
            if (account) {
                token = Object.assign({}, token, { access_token: account.access_token });
            }
            return token
        },
        async session({ session, token }) {
            if (session) {
                session = Object.assign({}, session, { access_token: token.access_token })
                console.log(session, "SESSION FROM CONSOLE ");
                console.log(token, "token from conse");
            }
            return session
        },

        async signIn({ user, profile, account, credentials, }) {
            console.log(user, profile, account, credentials, "FROM SIGNIN CALLBACK CONSOLE");
            try {
                const GoogleUserLoginDataToBackend = await axios.post(`${domain}/user_login`, {
                    user_name: session.user.name,
                    user_email: session.user.email,
                    access_token: session.access_token
                })
                console.log(GoogleUserLoginDataToBackend, "flask backend call");
            }
            catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            return true

        }


    },

    jwt: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
})
```

my Login.jsx

````
   <button
                                    onClick={handleGoogleLogin}
                                    className="w-full max-w-xs font-bold shadow-sm rounded-lg py-3 bg-indigo-100 text-gray-800 flex items-center justify-center transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out focus:outline-none hover:shadow focus:shadow-sm focus:shadow-outline"
                                >
                                    <div className="bg-white p-2 rounded-full">
                                        <svg className="w-4" viewBox="0 0 533.5 544.3">
                                            <path
                                                d="M533.5 278.4c0-18.5-1.5-37.1-4.7-55.3H272.1v104.8h147c-6.1 33.8-25.7 63.7-54.4 82.7v68h87.7c51.5-47.4 81.1-117.4 81.1-200.2z"
                                                fill="#4285f4"
                                            />
                                            <path
                                                d="M272.1 544.3c73.4 0 135.3-24.1 180.4-65.7l-87.7-68c-24.4 16.6-55.9 26-92.6 26-71 0-131.2-47.9-152.8-112.3H28.9v70.1c46.2 91.9 140.3 149.9 243.2 149.9z"
                                                fill="#34a853"
                                            />
                                            <path
                                                d="M119.3 324.3c-11.4-33.8-11.4-70.4 0-104.2V150H28.9c-38.6 76.9-38.6 167.5 0 244.4l90.4-70.1z"
                                                fill="#fbbc04"
                                            />
                                            <path
                                                d="M272.1 107.7c38.8-.6 76.3 14 104.4 40.8l77.7-77.7C405 24.6 339.7-.8 272.1 0 169.2 0 75.1 58 28.9 150l90.4 70.1c21.5-64.5 81.8-112.4 152.8-112.4z"
                                                fill="#ea4335"
                                            />
                                        </svg>
                                    </div>
                                    <span className="ml-4">Sign Up with Google</span>
                                </button>
    ```
````

```
const handleGoogleLogin = async () => {

    try {
        await signIn('google');
        const user = session?.data?.user;

        if (user) {
            console.log(user);
        }
    }
    catch (err) {

        console.log(err, "errrr");


    }

};
const { data: session } = useSession();
console.log(useSession());
console.log(session);
```

```
Console result ->
{
    "user": {
        "name": "my name returned from google",
        "email": "my email",
        "image": "my google profile image"
    },
    "expires": "expiry date",
    "access_token": "the access token"
}
```

Can somebody please help me as to how do i send the name email and access_token to my backend with an api call after successful login

currently the google auth is working great and i even get the user details in the console, output shared above but the api to my backend IS NOT BEING CALLED

Comment: No yelling please.    Storing the access token isnt a good idea its going to expire after an hour.